# Looping into List<> doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#

I'm filling a list of `Tir` object whith many user inputs :

**Tir class**

```
class Tir
{
    public int coup {  get; set; }
    public int noire { get; set; }
    public int angle { get; set; }
}
```

**user inputs**

```
Console.WriteLine("NOIRE");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("ANGLE 1");
int a1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("ANGLE 2");
int a2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("PAR");
int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("TANT");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then I have perform code with some calculations :

```
int[] anglearray = new int[] { a1, a2 };
anglearray = anglearray.Where(angle => angle > 0).ToArray();

List<Tir> rangelist = new List<Tir>();
List<Tir> FireList = new List<Tir>();

for (int a = 0; a <= anglearray.Count()-1; a++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= p-1; i++) 
    {

        Tir t = new Tir();

        t.noire = n;
        t.angle = anglearray[a];

        rangelist.Add(t);
    }
}

rangelist.Reverse();
for (int j = 0 ; j <= x-1; j++)
{
    rangelist.Reverse();
    FireList.AddRange(rangelist);
}
```

The problem is when I try to assign the `coup` property to the actual `Tir` object :

```
int nb_coup = 0;
foreach (Tir t in FireList)
{
    nb_coup++;
    t.coup = nb_coup;

    //THIS WORK
    Console.WriteLine($"{t.coup}  {t.noire}  {t.angle}");
}

foreach (Tir ti in FireList)
{
    //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    Console.WriteLine($"{ti.coup}  {ti.noire}  {ti.angle}");
}

Console.Read();
```

**EXAMPLE :**
*INPUTS*

```
n = 5200
a1 = 1600
a2 = 0
p = 3
x = 2
```

*OUTPUTS of the first* `foreach(Tir t in FireList)` ** THIS IS WHAT I WANT

```
1  5600  1600
2  5600  1600
3  5600  1600
4  5600  1600
5  5600  1600
6  5600  1600
```

This work, but I need to iterate in the list an other time, and then I got this OUTPUT in the second `foreach(Tir ti in FireList)`

```
6  5600  1600
5  5600  1600
4  5600  1600
4  5600  1600
5  5600  1600
6  5600  1600
```

Well, I really don't understant why the output is not the same, while I'm using the same method to access my Object. Why does the property change between the two foreach ?

Comment: Your `rangelist` contains three elements. You add that triplet to `FireList` twice, so each unique element is present in `FireList` twice. So you assign each element's `coup` twice. The second assignment naturally overwrites the first, leaving you with `4, 5, 6`.

Comment: You could declare `Tir` as a `struct` instead of a `class`  But then you'll find that modifying  the iterator variable `t` in your `foreach (Tir t in FireList)` loop is pointless, but rather you want to assign a new `Tir` to each element of the list.  Either way you'll find yourself either creating a new `Tir` for the elements that need different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your List only contains 3 distinct objects. `FireList[0]` and `FireList[5]` are pointing to the same object, so when you set `FireList[0].coup = 1`, `FireList[5]` also changes. Similarly when you set `FireList[5].coup = 6` then `FireList[0].coup` also becomes 6.

Your output is correct on the first pass because you're setting the value then immediately printing it. In the first loop your coup values will be:

1 0 0 0 0 1, 1 2 0 0 2 1, 1 2 3 3 2 1, 1 2 4 4 2 1, 1 5 4 4 5 1, 6 5 4 4 5 6.

However on the second pass the values of coup will be as they were at the end of the first pass, Ie 6 5 4 4 5 6.

Comment: well, i understand what's making a probleme, but does it mean that in a List, two object with the same value will have the same pointer ?

Comment: @Xeno6x, but they are not two objects. That's the problem. You have added the same objects to the list multiple times. There are no pointers here. Multiple list items refer to the same object. If you change that object through one of those items, the other item(s) will reflect that change. You can confirm this for yourself by comparing each item in the list to each other item using `==`. The comparison will be `true` if and only if two items refer to the same object.

Comment: You can have two objects with the same value and different pointers in a list, thats fine, but they have to be different objects. Ie you have to Clone them, or create new objects. In your case `Reverse` doesn't create new objects, it just reverses the list.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I managed to resolve this by creating another object that containt the number, and the list with noire & angle. I think it's not the best way, a little bit harcoding but it works haha.

Thanks for your help